# Serializing an object which has a non-serializable parent class

Tags: java, serialization

How does the below code work?

```
     class A {
         int a = 10;
     }


     class B extends A implements Serializable{

      }



     public class Test {
       public static void main(String[] args){
        B obj = new B();
        obj.a = 25;


        //Code to serialize object B  (B b= new B()),
         // deserialize it and print the value of 'a'. 
      }
    }
```

The code prints 10 even though I have changed the value of 'a' in the code.

Any explanation for this behaviour ?

Comment: The no-args constructor of the most derived non-`Serializable` base class is executed, the other classes of the object are deserialised as expected.

Comment: You should use a Serialization Proxy Pattern to properly serialize it (i.e. also serialize the parent fields). See for example http://java.dzone.com/articles/serialization-proxy-pattern

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default value of `a` is 10 - it will be set to 10 when the object is created. If you want to have a realistic test, set it to a different value after instantiation and then serialize it.

As for your update - if a class is not serializable, its fields are not serialized and deserialized. Only the fields of the serializable subclasses.

Comment: Exactly. Your answer contradicts my output. A is not serializable. But still I get printed a = 10, even though I change the value to 25 while created instance B.

Comment: @cmv - yes.. because it is the default value. 25 is _not_ serialized because A is not serializable. I don't see a contradiction

Answer (score 7):

Since `B` extends `A`, it **is an** `A`. This means that `b instanceof Serializable` returns `true`.

So, as long as the object you try to serialize returns true for the `instanceof Serializable` checks, you can serialize it. This applies for any composite objects contained within this object itself.

But you can't do `A a = new A();` and attempt to serialize `a`.

Consider this:

`java.lang.Object` doesn't implement `Serializable`. So, no one would've been able to serialize any objects in Java in that case! However, that's not the case at all. Also, in projects where there are multiple JavaBeans involved that extend a common super type, the general practice is to make this super type implement `Serializable` so that all the sub classes don't have to do that.

Comment: +1 for the Object  comparison. But you should add why the default value of A is used.

Comment: sorry, didn't realize you are answering the original (now modified) question, taking back the -1

Comment: @Bozho: Which one? I've only explained the ability to serialize, not whether the states of fields will be saved/restored. So, doesn't whatever I've told make complete sense?

Comment: @Bozho: I think I was a tad too late in refreshing :)

Comment: This is incomprehensible. The second sentence doesn't follow from the first sentence. It is B that is Serializable, not A. So you *can* do B b = new B() etc. I don't know what 'however, that's not the case at all' is supposed to mean. And finally, it doesn't answer the question in any way shape or form.

Answer (score 2):

If class B extends class A, and A is not serializable, then all the instance variables of class A are initialized with their default values (which is 10 in this case) after de-serialization of class B.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a serializable class, but your superclass is NOT serializable, then any instance variables you INHERIT from that superclass will be reset to the values they were given during the original construction of the object. This is because the non- serializable class constructor WILL run! In fact, every constructor ABOVE the first non-serializable class constructor will also run, no matter what, because once the first super constructor is invoked, (during deserialization), it of course invokes its super constructor and so on up the inheritance tree.

Answer (score 0):

If a parent class is not serializable its fields are initialised each time the object is deserialized. i.e. The object still needs to be constructed.

Comment: Confusing. Don't you mean the object still *is* constructed, at least its non-Serializable base classes?